# problem in using grep with a pattern file

Tags: grep, regular-expression

Am using the following command

```
grep -Fwf tmp.txt csw15int.txt > temp.txt
```

tmp.txt is the pattern file. Each line is matched with lines in csw15int.txt. I want only the first word in csw15int.txt to be matched with the lines from tmp.txt. Presently, it searches for a match in the entire line.

Comment: Have not tried this but will replacing `f tmp.txt` with ``cut -d\  -f1 tmp.txt`` fix the problem?  You have to enclose the `cut` command in backward quotes.

Comment: You need to provide sample input and expected output. There are many ways to achieve something like this, but you need to be more specific.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, these questions are much easier to answer if you show the input and output.  However....

Since you're using `-F`, I know that your patterns are fixed strings, not regexes.

Assuming you don't care about the order, you can just use [`join`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/join.html).

The only caveat is that you have to sort the input first.  (Note that's *lexicographic* sorting, not numeric.)

Assuming Bash or another shell with process substitution:

```
join <(sort tmp.txt) <(sort csw15int.txt) > temp.txt
```